# Raspberry Pi can't talk to i2c Sensor

Tags: sensors, raspbian, i2c, raspberry-pi2

I have a gas sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi 2 (5V,GND, SDA, SCL)
I use the Raspbian OS.
I try to communicate with the sensor according to this manual:

http://co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN142-RaspberryPi-K_series.pdf

i2cdetect delivers the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 69 -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

The sensor should have an address of 0x68, im not sure why there is something on 69. But that is not my problem.

I wrote the following test program:
( http://www.byvac.com/downloads/sws/notsmb_1_0.zip )

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6               File: test.py

from notsmb import notSMB

bus = notSMB(I2CBUS)

resp = bus.i2c(0x68,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)

print(resp)
```

But I get write errors all the time

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    resp = bus.i2c(0x68,[0x22,0x00,0x08,0x2A],4)
TypeError: Error write fail
```

Comment: This might be a good place for your question too: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com